# PHP Switch case help. Should be simple?

Tags: php, arrays, switch-statement

i'm creating this banner rotating PHP script (I'm new to PHP) and was wondering why my cases aren't working. I can get the random image to show via the array although I can't seem to make the cases work.

I would like it so if the image from the random array is the 0 image, it will say visit jackhair.co.uk and if the random image from the array is 2 it will say jamiehair.co.uk

```
<?php
/*Creates an array called banners which holds all the images of banners */
$banners=array("img/reversessh.jpg","img/failtwo.jpg","img/iptable.jpg");
$random = ($banners[(rand(0,2))]);
$visit = $random;

switch($visit)
{
case $visit = 0:
    Echo "Visit www.jackhair.co.uk";
    break;
case $visit = 1:
    Echo "Visit www.lukehair.co.uk";
    break;
case $visit = 2:
     Echo "Visit www.jamiehair.co.uk";
    break;
default:
    null;
}

?>

<img src="<?= $random ?>" alt="Rotating Banners" />
```

Hope you can help! Thankyou.

Comment: Why wouldn't you stick to the arrays? Much easier. Make the url the array key, and the image the value, then you can just show a random array value without any switch.

Comment: Mixed case keywords (`Echo`) will work afaik, but it's good practice to write them as they appear in the manual. Lower-case for keywords, camel case for classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
$visit = rand(0,2);
$random = $banners[$visit];
```

Instead of other way around. That way you keep the int value random in the $visit variable and not a image url.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is incorrect. You only need to use the value in the case statement:

```
switch($visit)
{
    case 'img/reversessh.jpg':
        echo "Visit www.jackhair.co.uk";
        break;
    case 'img/failtwo.jpg':
        echo "Visit www.lukehair.co.uk";
        break;
    case 'img/iptable.jpg':
        echo "Visit www.jamiehair.co.uk";
        break;
    default:
        null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Just tried this and it's still the same. The image changes but it is just stuck on www.jackhair.co.uk

Comment: In his code, `$visit` is going to be a string (one of the `$banners` array elements) not an integer at all.

Comment: While the substance of my answer is still correct the code would not be. I've updated to reflect their actual values.

Comment: Counteracting undeclared downvote, seems fine to me.